# Reproducing Model results from RandomizedSearchCV

Tags: python, scikit-learn, hyperparameters

I have used RandomizedSearchCV to tune the parameters of my Random Forest model, as in the code cell below:

```
rf_random = RandomizedSearchCV(estimator = rf, param_distributions = random_grid, 
                               n_iter = 100, cv = 3, verbose=2, random_state=42, n_jobs = -1)
rf_random.fit(X_train[rf_cols], y_train)
```

It turns out that the rf_random model outperforms any of my manually trained models with the same parameters which were retrieved using

```
rf_random.best_params_
```

I need to reproduce the exact prediction that I have made using RandomizedSearchCV, but I am unable to do so, mainly due to two reasons:

1. best_params_ differ on each run
2. I am having trouble understanding how RandomizedSearchCV splits the data into train set and validation set, which means that it is nearly impossible for me to train a new model that behaves the same.

What can I do? What more information do I need to reproduce the results? Or is it even possible to reproduce results from RandomizedSearchCV, despite the fact that I have fixed my random_state to 42? Should I stick to GridSearchCV instead if I need to reproduce the results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you are looking for the `best_estimator_` attribute of `RandomizedSearchCV` which will return the fitted estimator which scored highest on the left out data:

```py
kf = KFold(n_splits=3, random_state=42)

rf_random = RandomizedSearchCV(estimator = rf, param_distributions = random_grid, 
                               n_iter = 100, cv = kf, verbose=2, random_state=42, n_jobs = -1)
rf_random.fit(X_train[rf_cols], y_train)

tuned_rf = rf_random.best_estimator_
for train_index, test_index in kf.split(X_train[rf_cols], y_train):
    # use train and test indices here
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Would there be a way for me to find out which portion of the data the model used to train the model?

Comment: The best way I can think of is to not specify `cv=3` but use a cv splitter like `Kfold` instead. Then you can retrieve the indices for each split with its `split()` method. Will update the answer to reflect this.